Soldering electric guitar to fix ground buzz and headset
The guitar jack looks alright, there is a tiny amount of fraying on the positive wire but  95% of all the wires are solidly soldered in. There is a buzz coming from the guitar which seems to be known as ground buzz, since it disappears as soon as I touch metal parts of the guitar. Is it worth resoldering the jack? I just don't see any obvious defect.
I attempted to fix a headset but I found that the blobs of solder previously found on top of the 'circuit board'(?) are partially gone so I don't know how to attach the wires. Seems difficult to reapply solder and make it stick.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Jonathan, There are sites on the web that will walk you step by step through a process to find the exact location of the problem and how to fix it. I've seen them. They are good and will help you. I just don't have one handy today. But they shouldn't be hard to find. It will involve making specific cables and connections. But it is fairly bullet proof. You will have to follow steps and do some work. No escaping that. Best wishes.

Guitar buzz

Player’s Body Not Grounded: When the guitar player touches the strings, does the hum stop? This indicates that the player’s body is acting as one plate of a capacitor.


The capacitance between the body and power wiring adds to the capacitance between the guitar and power wiring, increasing the level of the hum transmitted from the power wiring to the guitar. (Incidentally, the same thing happens if you replace the player’s body with a sheet of aluminum foil).

Source: Jazz Me.
Headphones
The wires are probably insulated with some sort of varnish-like coating. This has to be removed before tinning with solder and then soldering to the connector. A YouTube web search for headphone repair should give plenty of results.
Tip: in future, don't ask multiple questions in one post. The SE format is one question per thread.

Guitar Buzz: All guitars are not especially tightly shielded against external fields. Quite high impedance levels in traditional passive guitar electronics do not kill the caught buzzes by loading them dead. When you touch the metal parts you become a part of the shielding, because the metal parts are generally connected to the ground side of the output connector. Actually you easily shield so well that the buzz virtually vanishes if it's caused by the electric fields of the mains AC wires and lamps in the room.
Magnetic fields of transformers and electric motors are not affected by your body. You must use your feet to walk further from such items if your guitar has non-humbucking single coil mics. Turning a little often helps, too.
Having tight enough grounded metal shield around guitar electronics and using a high quality instrument cable do the same as touching the metal parts. Pro instrument service companies can make the shielding tight but you can do the same if you watch at first some tutorials.
In theory it's possible that you have a still undetected ground wire breakage inside your guitar. We cannot see it, but you have a possibility to find it. A long not so well grounded branch in the guitar wiring can increase dramatically the ability to catch buzzes.
Fixing the headphones: Impossible for us, because the phones are not here. See tutorials or find local help. Repairing electronics is today far from trivial because manufacturing economy and easy to repairing collide badly.
